# Using Regular Expression to validate the following requirement?

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to validate a number exactly 15 digits with 5 digits group separated by "-" , ":" , "/", that should start with either 5 or 4 or 37, it also should not contain any characters.

It means

37344-37747-27744 - valid
40344-37747-27744 - valid
59344-37747-27744 - valid
37344:37747:27744 - valid
37344/37747/27744 - valid
87887-98734-83422 - Not valid
548aa:aa764:90887 - not valid
37759\29938\92093 - not valid

I was only able to go this far

```
\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}
```

Please help.

Comment: Is it okay to have different separators for each group, e.g. `37344:12242/12435`? Also, do you want every group to start with either 5, 4, and 37 or just the first one?

Comment: Does this work? https://regex101.com/r/72nUFo/1

Comment: Sorry if the question was not detailed. Only the first group needed to be starting with 5, 4 or 37 and only one type of characters can separate them i.e. ":", "-" or "/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use look ahead `(?=.)` to first check if your string starts `^` with numbers `5|4|37` that is the requirement, here's full pattern:

```
^(?=5|4|37)\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}$
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/GqYbuR/1)

Comment: Thank you also, i was looking for the use of  "^" ,"$".

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
(((5|4)\d{4})|((37)\d{3}))[-:\/]\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}
```

https://regex101.com/r/VvTq5P/1

**Edit:**

I would also add: `\b` at the beggining and at the end:

```
\b(((5|4)\d{4})|((37)\d{3}))[-:\/]\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}\b
```

so nothing like:

```
12337344-37747-27744
```

can pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the regex is this:

```
((5|4)\d{4}|37\d{3})[-:\/]\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}
```

Needs to be

4XXXX, 5XXXX or 37XXX

So I split it up to accept the 3 forms

Answer (score 1):

```
((5|4)\d{4}|37\d{3})[-:\/]\d{5}[-:\/]\d{5}
```

(5|4)\d{4} - looks for a number that starts with either 5 or 4 and four digits afterward.

Then the or 37\d{3} looks for 37 and three digits afterward.

Answer (score 0):

If the separators have to be the same:

```
^(?=37|[54])\d{5}([-:\/])\d{5}\1\d{5}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=37|[54])` Positive lookahead, assert either `37` or `5` or `4` to the right
- `\d{5}` Match 5 digits
- `([-:\/])` Capture **group 1**, match one of `-` `:` `/`
- `\d{5}` Match 5 digits
- `\1` Backreference to match the same separator as in group 1
- `\d{5}` Match 5 digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/i4qioC/1).

```js
const regex = /^(?=37|[54])\d{5}([-:\/])\d{5}\1\d{5}$/;
[
  "37344-37747-27744",
  "40344-37747-27744",
  "59344-37747-27744",
  "37344:37747:27744",
  "37344/37747/27744",
  "87887-98734-83422",
  "548aa:aa764:90887",
  "37759\\29938\\92093",
  "37344-37747/27744",
  "37344:37747-27744"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
)
```

The pattern without a lookaround using an alternation:

```
^(?:37\d{3}|[54]\d{4})([-:\/])\d{5}\1\d{5}$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VQKtTx/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?:37\d{3}|[54]\d{4})([-:\/])\d{5}\1\d{5}$/;
[
  "37344-37747-27744",
  "40344-37747-27744",
  "59344-37747-27744",
  "37344:37747:27744",
  "37344/37747/27744",
  "87887-98734-83422",
  "548aa:aa764:90887",
  "37759\\29938\\92093",
  "37344-37747/27744",
  "37344:37747-27744"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
)
```